# VBA Formula property list separator

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have set in Windows 10 regional settings semicolon (;) as list separator.
I have Office 2019 Excel. If I fill manually in an excel cell a formula having a parameters list, like e.g.

```
=SUMXMY2($A$9;$D$9)
```

I must use semicolon because a comma (,) gives me an error.
However, if I fill the cell from VBA running code using the VBA Formula property I must use colon because using semicolon gives me run-time error 1004.
Here is the involved code line that works fine:

```
cc.Formula = "=SUMXMY2($A$9,$D$9)"
```

And here the one that gives error:

```
cc.Formula = "=SUMXMY2($A$9;$D$9)"
```

My question to community:
Is there any rational explanation to this (apparently) irrational behavior?

As far as I understand the above line codes passes exactly the test string that is written between double quotes. So the semicolon should work and the comma should not. But it is exactly the opposite!
Thanks for the attention

Comment: `.FormulaLocal`